# Use a loop to recode values?

Tags: r

I have a df like this (seasondate has values from 1:84, and I have columns day1:day84):

```
seasondate    day1   day2   day3   day4   day5   
1              0       0     0       0      0        
4              0       0     0       0      0      
1              0       0     0       0      0      
5              0       0     0       0      0
```

If the day"x" matches the seasondate, I need the value to be 1, so it looks like this:

```
seasondate    day1   day2   day3   day4   day5   
1              1       0     0       0      0       
4              0       0     0       1      0      
1              1       0     0       0      0      
5              0       0     0       0      1
```

I haven't been able to make a loop work, so I'm currently (and shamefully) repeating the following code 84 times to make it work:

```
trial$day1[trial$seasondate==1] <- 1
trial$day2[trial$seasondate==2] <- 1
...
trial$day84[trial$seasondate==84] <- 1
```

Please help me make this more concise

Comment: I want trial$day2[trial$seasondate==2] <- 1, so it's always binary. Sorry, will edit question

Comment: Thanks Zheyuan. Is there a way I could write that so I keep all of my 84 'day' columns, even if there is no seasondate to match that day (so every value in the column would be 0)?